# How to get results ordered by 3 maximum values?

Tags: mysql

I have a database results showing for the offer offer as `TEXT`, I also tried it in offer field in `VARCHAR`

**My results (offer field has values):**

```
mark 1234 | peter 201 | zara 449 |lily 2145
```

This did not work (even if offers as `TEXT` and `VARCHAR`):

```
select name, offer from friends ORDER BY offer DESC LIMIT 3
```

**Result:** `mark 1234 | peter 201 | zara 449` - Wrong

This only works for 1 result (But I want 3 results):

```
select name, max(offer) from friends ORDER BY offer DESC LIMIT 3
```

**Result:** `lily 2145`

What I really would like is to have this result:

```
mark 1234 | lily 2145 | zara 449
```

Comment: You need to put Offer in INT not text values

Comment: Inazo was correct! Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you have offer as string the value is ordered by char so if you need an order by number you could use a cast to integer (unsignef) in order by

```
select name, offer 
from friends ORDER BY cast(offer AS UNISGNED) DESC LIMIT 3
```

Answer (score 0):

I think there is a silly mistake, just select offer instead of max

```
select name, offer from friends ORDER BY offer DESC LIMIT 3
```

Comment: And then to set offer to INT in table as suggested by Inazo above!